# Find a solution for $(2x-4y+6)dx + (x+y-3)dy = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can you, please, help me to find the solution of:

$$(2x-4y+6)dx + (x+y-3)dy = 0$$

I tried to transform it into exact form, but it did not work. Failed to find integrating factor.

Comment: you can reduce it to homogeneous form and use $y = vx$ do you want via IF?

Comment: now, I'm not sure which way is better...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$ x=3-y \wedge 2(3-y)-4y+6=0 \\  x=1 \wedge y=2 \\ k=x-1; \ t=y-2 \\ x=k+1; \ y=t+2 \\ dk=dx;  \ dt=dy \\ (2k-4t)dk=(k+t)dt \\ z(k)=\frac{t}{k} \\ ... $

Answer (score 1):

solving 2x-4y+6=0 and x+y -3 =0 hence x =1,y =2

Sifting origin to (1,2)

Hence

x = x'+1, and y = y'+2

Hence 2x - 4y +6 = 2(x'+1) - 4(y'+2) +6 = 2x'+2 - 4y' - 8 +6 = 2x' - 4y'
and x+y -3 = x'+1+y'+2 -3 = x'+y' and dx = dx' ,dy = dy'

Hence $\frac{dx}{dy} = -\frac{x+y-3}{2x-4y+6}$

Hence $\frac{dx'}{dy'} = -\frac{x'+y'}{2x'-4y'} = -\frac{1+\frac{y'}{x'}}{2-4\frac{y'}{x'}}$

now take $\frac{y'}{x'} = v$

$y' = vx'$

$\frac{dy'}{dx'} = v+x'\frac{dv}{dx'}$

Now $\frac{dx'}{dy'} = -\frac{x'+y'}{2x'-4y'} = -\frac{1+\frac{y'}{x'}}{2-4\frac{y'}{x'}}$

$v+x'\frac{dv}{dx'} = -\frac{1+v}{2-4v}$

Now convert into variable saperable form to get then solve it to get the final answer